# Periodic timer not working as expected on TM4C123 MCU

Tags: microcontroller, c, embedded, programming

I am starting to learn how to use timers/interrupts on the TM4C123 evaluation board (TM4C123GH6PM MCU).

In this example I am configuring a timer to create 1 second delays to toggle an on-board LED on and off. But when I run the code in real time on the board, the red LED appears to be on all the time. If I step through the code with breakpoints in my `while(1)` loop where I poll the timer register, it appears to work fine. (I am not using interrupts with this timer, just polling).

I haven't attached the individual register breakdowns from the datasheet as there are quite a few.

Has anyone got any ideas as to why this is not working as expected?

Below is my code for the example I am following from the TM4C123 datasheet:

[image]

And here is my code:

```
        #include "include/tm4c123gh6pm.h"
        #define RED_LED (1U << 1)
        #define BLUE_LED (1U << 2)
        #define GREEN_LED (1U << 3)

        int main()
        {
            SYSCTL_RCGCGPIO_R = 0x20U;              //Enabling clock to port F.
            GPIO_PORTF_LOCK_R = 0x4C4F434BU;    //Unlocking the port F lock register.
            GPIO_PORTF_CR_R = 0xFFU;                    //Enabling the port F commit register.
            GPIO_PORTF_DIR_R = 0x0EU;                   //Setting the port F pins as outputs. 
            GPIO_PORTF_DEN_R = 0x1FU;                   //Enabling digital writing to port F.


    /*  To use a GPTM, the appropriate TIMERn bit must be set in the RCGCTIMER or RCGCWTIMER
            register (see page 338 and page 357). If using any CCP pins, the clock to the appropriate GPIO
            module must be enabled via the RCGCGPIO register (see page 340). To find out which GPIO port
            to enable, refer to Table 23-4 on page 1344. Configure the PMCn fields in the GPIOPCTL register to
            assign the CCP signals to the appropriate pins (see page 688 and Table 23-5 on page 1351).  */

            SYSCTL_RCGCTIMER_R = 0x01U;     //Enable timer 0 clock signal.

    /*  1. Ensure the timer is disabled (the TnEN bit in the GPTMCTL register is cleared) before making
            any changes.    */

            TIMER0_CTL_R &= ~(1<<0);            //Disabling timer.

    /*  2. Write the GPTM Configuration Register (GPTMCFG) with a value of 0x0000.0000. */

            TIMER0_CFG_R = 0x00000000U;     //Writing 0 hex to this register.


    /*  3. Configure the TnMR field in the GPTM Timer n Mode Register (GPTMTnMR):
            a. Write a value of 0x1 for One-Shot mode.
            b. Write a value of 0x2 for Periodic mode.  */

            TIMER0_TAMR_R |= (0x2<<0);      //Setting timer 0 to periodic mode.


/*  4. Optionally configure the TnSNAPS, TnWOT, TnMTE, and TnCDIR bits in the GPTMTnMR register
        to select whether to capture the value of the free-running timer at time-out, use an external
        trigger to start counting, configure an additional trigger or interrupt, and count up or down.  */

        TIMER0_TAMR_R &= ~(1<<4);           //Configured as count down timer.

/*  5. Load the start value into the GPTM Timer n Interval Load Register (GPTMTnILR).   */

        TIMER0_TAILR_R = 0x00F42400;    //16,000,000Mhz clock,  1 sec delays.

/*  6. If interrupts are required, set the appropriate bits in the GPTM Interrupt Mask Register
        (GPTMIMR).  */

        //Interrupts are not used, I am polling the timer0 regsiter as seen below in while(1) loop.

/*  7. Set the TnEN bit in the GPTMCTL register to enable the timer and start counting. */

        TIMER0_CTL_R |= (1<<0);             //Enabling timer 

/*  8. Poll the GPTMRIS register or wait for the interrupt to be generated (if enabled). In both cases,
        the status flags are cleared by writing a 1 to the appropriate bit of the GPTM Interrupt Clear
        Register (GPTMICR). */

        while(1)
        {
            if( (TIMER0_RIS_R & 0x00000001) == 1)   //Checking if timer has finished counting.
            TIMER0_ICR_R |= (1<<0);                             //Clearing the finished timing bit in TIMER0_RIS_R.
            GPIO_PORTF_DATA_R ^= (1U << 1);             //Toggling the RED_LED output.  
        }
    }
```

Comment: So maybe you have the LED connected to the wrong place?

Comment: Thanks Andy. I think it is correct. The LED I mention is a RGB type built directly onto the board, connected to port F pins 1, 2 and 3 (bits 1, 2 and 3 of the Port F GPIO DATA register).

Comment: There is a Timers example that basically does this in TivaWare, have you had a look at that program?

Comment: @Tyler I didn’t know there was. Have you got a link for the program by any chance?

Comment: Sure, but it is a really easy thing to search for.  http://www.ti.com/tool/SW-TM4C

Comment: I am still interested to know why my code doesn’t run correctly if there are any TI experienced people that wouldn’t mind helping.

Comment: I assume this is for a school assignment, so that is why you are not using the TI Peripheral Driver Libraries?

Comment: Not a school assignment. I studied this MCU as part of a module previously, but now trying to learn some more advanced functions out of interest in my spare time. Information on this evaluation board is very limited.

Comment: Tons of information about this board here http://www.ti.com/tool/EK-TM4C123GXL

Comment: So from your links, I gather that this device is designed to be used with the peripheral device driver libraries?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your while loop, you forgot your squiggly brackets.

It should be:

```
        while(1)
    {
        if( (TIMER0_RIS_R & 0x00000001) == 1)   //Checking if timer has finished counting.
        {
             TIMER0_ICR_R |= (1<<0);                             //Clearing the finished timing bit in TIMER0_RIS_R.
             GPIO_PORTF_DATA_R ^= (1U << 1);             //Toggling the RED_LED output.  
        }
    }
```

Comment: Wow, thank you very much Tyler for spotting that. Just compiled and downloaded the code, it now works exactly as expected.